# Return a JSONObject through Spring MappingJackson2JsonView

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I Have xml and json output view for my spring project. I'm using spring 4 version and This is the my ViewResolver xml file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
       <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
       <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </map>
  </property>

  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
      </bean>

      <!-- JAXB XML View -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
               <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>    
                   <value>com.rest.dto.SportInfoDtoList</value>
                </list>
               </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
     </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

</bean>
```

I want to pass Jackson JSONObject through my controller using ModelAndView.

```
@RequestMapping(value="stat", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getSeasonteamStat(@ModelAttribute(value="statDto") StatDto statDto){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    try{
        String seasonteamstatStr = GuideStatClient.getSeasonTeamStats();
        JSONObject seasonteamstat = new JSONObject(seasonteamstatStr);
        model.addObject("seasonteamstat", seasonteamstat);
        return model;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return model;
    }
}
```

If I return `seasonteamstatStr` it will return successfully. But I need to pass this string as a json objet. `This is a huge object so I dont want to map it into java objects using JAXB.`

So is there have any way to pass this string as a json. I tried jackson and gson JSONObject. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate your method with `@ResponseBody` which  indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body and change the return type to `String`